# PSQL run from shell script - command not found?

Tags: bash, shell, psql

I try to execute an PSQL from shell, and the thing is - it returns the error "command not found". I have a shell script in which there're lines:

```
ID3=`more DATA/Id3.txt`
psql -h localhost test test -Atc "SELECT id, reference, timestamp FROM restricted WHERE id='`$ID3`'"
```

In the Id3.txt there's only the ID. When the psql command is written and executed direct through prompt - there's no problem at all and correct value is returned. When executed with a .sh file - error "command not found" is brought up. I have no clue why. Maybe anyone have a idea?

Comment: Do you get the same message if you run the `psql -h ...` command from your prompt?

Comment: Do you have the path to the binary in your PATH variable?

Comment: when running from prompt I get the ID from DB. It won't work only when run with a script

Comment: The error message is from the shell. The SQL command itself has nothing to do with it. The error kicks in an earlier stage. `psql` is not found.

Answer (score 1):

In your script try to add `which psql` to see whether you can find the executable

Answer (score 1):

Run below command on your console: `whereis psql`
And then replace `psql` inyour script with the output of above command. This